# How does this operation give me these values?

Tags: c++, operators

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    x = x + ++y % x;
    y = --x / y + x * y;
    cout<< "x= " << x << endl;
    cout << "y= " << y << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

let the inputs be x=6 and y=8

How is x = 8 and not 9 and how is y=72 not 73

How I calculated it:

x=6+ 9mod(6)=9

y=((9-1)/8)+9*8=73

what did I do wrong here ??

Comment: `y = --x / y + x * y;` is arguably hostile code.  Which `x` should be evaluated first?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: Do not modify the variable you are using as part of an expression.

Comment: You may want to read about sequence points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: @DrewDormann Not just arguably.  Overtly.

Comment: @PaulSanders  Undefined behaviour means any outcome is possible.   No observable symptoms (i.e. the code behaves as a programmer expects, at least during the testing that programmer does) and covert hostility are also potential consequences.

Comment: If you want that first value to be `(9-1)` write it that way. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" -Brian Kernighan.

Comment: @DrewDormann isn't there a certain order of operations?

Comment: @PoliceProgrammer the compiler warnings that I've turned on [say no](https://godbolt.org/z/a3oh4aqY5).  However, some might say that no reasonable programmer should write `--x / y + x * y`, or any code that could be interpreted multiple ways.

Comment: C++ is not a nanny language.  It gives you enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: Takes real skill to shoot yourself with a rope.